# What is the most efficient strategy for winning in Campaign mode?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have access to Barbarians, Archers, Goblins, and Giants - but I still tend to have my entire army wiped out pretty quickly when playing the campaign.  I am stuck on "Brute Force" and "Gold Rush", and I can't seem to progress past them.  I'm sure there must be some strategy for how to use each unit, but generally mine just get cut down by the cannons - and typically they don't even fight back, instead focusing on looting other buildings.  What is an effective strategy for using units in Campaign mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Campaign levels are like puzzles, and typically require use of specific units and/or upgraded units to succeed - especially if you are seeking a 3 star result.  A few general tips for success -

- Use Tier 1 troops (barbarian, archer, goblin) in hordes to attack
  single target defenses (cannon, archer tower, spring traps).  You'll
  loose a few, but the horde will overcome.
- Use Tier 2 troops (giant, wall breaker, balloon) for their
  specialized abilities, particularly to crack splash damage defenses
  like the mortar, which can wipe out your hordes.  When using the
  balloon, be sure to wipe out air defense first.
- Campaign levels are not timed, so once defenses are down you can wait
  indefinitely to win if you want to save troops.
- Queue some troop production in your Barracks before starting a fight (even though you are full).  Some of these troops will already be ready and waiting as soon as you are complete.

For per level strategies, check out the level by level video guides [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Single_Player_Campaign).

I will also add that upgraded units help a lot.  As I now attack the high-end levels, it is much easier to 3 star now that I have most units upgraded to level 4 or level 5.  I also make use of the Barbarian King, which I believe makes these levels much easier since he is a very good tank, and can draw a lot of fire while your hordes disassemble the defenses.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in the goblin single player battles that there are a lot of spring traps and bombs that kill my barbs and archers pretty quick. After I have done a single player level I check the next level and train what I think I need. Building a lab helps as you can upgrade your troops. In multiplayer battles I usually train 10-15 giants, 1 balloon, 1-4 wizards and the rest archers, oh and 6-10 wallbreakers.

Comment: Hi @Mgoudi10 , welcome to Arqade!  Thanks for the answer.  I edited out the clan advertisement since it is not really part of the answer.  Probably the best place for that would be [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), although I'm not sure you'll find many clashers here in general.  Clash on chief!

Answer (score 1):

I use 10 level 2 dragons and 10 level 5 archers its slightly overpowered but its better this way than underpowered!

Answer (score 1):

A good strategy would be to use 16 Giants and 5 Wall Breakers, with the remainder being Barbarians or Archers.

Answer (score 0):

Use level 4 barbarians, level 4 archers and, if you can afford them, level 3 balloons.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use spells quite a lot my main attack force for online and campaign is 3 lv1 dragons with the rest wizards.